# Struct initialisation with large integer

Tags: c

So I have the following struct:

```c
typedef struct int64 {
    unsigned char value[8];
} int64;
```

Which I an using to represent a 64 bit integer (I know this exists in stdint.h but I thought it could be a good exercise to try and write it myself, and I plan to use this format for much larger integers). My question is there any way that I could initialize this struct with a binary string or an overlarge integer, something like:

```c
int64 number = 0b1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011001

// Or

int64 number = 1231823812738123878;  // Or something larger than 2^32
```

Thanks for any help you can give me :)

Comment: You could just `memcpy` an actual `uint64_t` number into the `value` array, but you do need to be aware of endianness. The answer by dbush assumes big-endian, which is typically not what you want when doing arbitrary precision math.

Comment: Unless you are concerned about you violating GPL, you can simply look how the quite common arbitrary precision library (GMP) https://gmplib.org/ does it. But keep in mind, that reading GPL software and then "stealing ideas" for proprietary solutions might be illegal.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to break it up byte by byte, since the struct contains an array of bytes:

```
int64 number = { { 0b10000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 
                   0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000, 0b00011001 } };
```

You can compress this using hex constants instead of binary constants:

```
int64 number = { { 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x19 } };
```

Comment: Yeah that's how I've been doing it up until now, the problem is that with much larger integers this process would become tedious, are you sure this is the only way of doing this?

Comment: You could make a union of this struct and a `uint64_t` and directly initialize the `uint64_t` member, but then there's not much use for the struct.

Comment: @Nathcat using a hex prefix `0x` would condense the amount of text, is there a reason you're set on using the binary `0b` prefix?

Comment: @yano no there wasn't any particular reason, I didn't think about hex though, that would help thanks :)

Comment: Re "*You could make a union of this struct and a uint64_t and directly initialize the uint64_t member*", 1) That would create machine-dependent behaviour. 2) It wouldn't be equivalent to the code in the answer on an x86/x86-64. The order of the bytes would be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

For a 64-bit number, you could get away with a macro:

```
#if USE_BIG_ENDIAN
#define INIT64(x) { (((x)|0ULL)>>56)&255, (((x)|0ULL)>>48)&255, \
                    (((x)|0ULL)>>40)&255, (((x)|0ULL)>>32)&255, \
                    (((x)|0ULL)>>24)&255, (((x)|0ULL)>>16)&255, \
                    (((x)|0ULL)>> 8)&255, (((x)|0ULL)>> 0)&255 }
#else
#define INIT64(x) { (((x)|0ULL)>> 0)&255, (((x)|0ULL)>> 8)&255, \
                    (((x)|0ULL)>>16)&255, (((x)|0ULL)>>24)&255, \
                    (((x)|0ULL)>>32)&255, (((x)|0ULL)>>40)&255, \
                    (((x)|0ULL)>>48)&255, (((x)|0ULL)>>56)&255 }
#endif

int64 number0 = INIT64(0);
int64 number1 = INIT64(0b1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011001);
int64 number2 = INIT64(1231823812738123878);
```

This approach alas won't work for larger types. Converting at runtime from a string representation is a classic solution.  You could also preprocess your source code with a utility that substitutes an appropriate syntax, such as `BIGNUM(x)` with the equivalent initializer.

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting approach, I'll look into that